# Why are some of the elements in my simulation being generated at different coordinates than specified?

Tags: python, simulation

I am trying to make a traffic simulator that requires generating vehicles across 4 lanes.

Following are the coordinates where the vehicles need to spawn:

```
x = {'right':[550,550,550], 'down':[755,727,697], 'left':[800,800,800], 'up':[602,627,657]}    
y = {'right':[348,370,398], 'down':[250,250,250], 'left':[498,466,436], 'up':[535,535,535]}
```

- 3 types of vehicles need to be generated "bus","car", and "bike"
  ,whose numbers are supplemented by my_dict along with the time of the signal for each traffic cycle at 4 lanes namely right, down, left and up.
- Vehicles need to be generated in a round robin fashion at
  right->down->left->up respectively.
- The function is able to generate
  the vehicles perfectly at specified locations for the first
  iteration, however on subsequent iterations, the "right" vehicles are
  spawned at coordinates X{0,0,0}(because them seem to be coming from
  the edge of the screen).
- The rest of vehicles for other lanes are
  spawning just fine at specified locations.

```
def generateVehicles():
    global vehicles
    dir_veh={
        0:'right',
        1:'down',
        2:'left',
        3:'up',
    }
    i=1
    for i in range(i,len(my_dict)+1):
        for j in range(4):
            vehicle_list=my_dict[str(i)][0][j]
                def for_loop_1():
                    Vehicle(random.randint(1,2), 'bus', j, dir_veh[j], random.randint(0,1))
                 
                def for_loop_2():
                    Vehicle(random.randint(1,2), 'car', j, dir_veh[j], random.randint(0,1))
               
                def for_loop_3():
                    Vehicle(random.randint(1,2), 'bike', j, dir_veh[j], random.randint(0,1))
       
            iterations_dict = {
                for_loop_1: vehicle_list[0],
                for_loop_2: vehicle_list[1],
                for_loop_3: vehicle_list[2]}
    
            iterations = [func for func, count in iterations_dict.items() for _ in range(count)]
            random.shuffle(iterations)
       
            # Calling the iterations in the shuffled order
            for iteration in iterations:
                iteration()

        sum_gr=sum(my_dict[str(i)][1])
        cycle_len=sum_gr+L
        time.sleep(cycle_len+4)
        i+=1
```

The below class is just a representative of the original class:

```
class Vehicle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self, lane, direction,):
            pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
            self.x = x[direction][lane]
            self.y = y[direction][lane]
            self.originalImage = pygame.image.load(path)
            self.currentImage = pygame.image.load(path)

        def render(self, screen):
            screen.blit(self.currentImage, (self.x, self.y))
```

I tried delaying the execution of the iteration() to see whether the vehicles are being generated in correct order, however they were.

Comment: The pygame part seems to have nothing to do with the problem. Most likely this is not a [tag:pygame] issue.

Comment: The line ```Vehicle(random.randint(1,2), 'bus', j, dir_veh[j], random.randint(0,1))``` doesn't match your vehicle signature as defined for the vehicle.__init__() method?

Comment: @Rabbid76 I think so too. Maybe it more like optimization issue

Comment: @itprorh66 It was for representation purpose only i didn't put the exact constructor here

Comment: Please fix the indentation of your code. The functions are needlessly indented, causing an `IndentationError`. It would also be useful if all the necessary imports and the rendering part, such that we can reproduce the problem of the incorrect rendering.